# How is it possible for these 2 functions, executed in parallel, to output an unlikely result?

Tags: assembly, concurrency, cpu-architecture

I have these 2 functions, executed in parallel :

```
int x = 10 // a common variable

void P1(){                   void P2(){
   while(1){                    while(1){
   x--;                         x--;
   x++;                         x++;
   if(x!=10)                    if(x!=10)
      printf("x=%d",x);             printf("x=%d",x);
   }                            }
}                             }

parbegin P1(); P2();
parend
```

The functions occasionally output **`x=8`**, which does not look possible.

Does it have to do with the fact that the **`x--`** and **`x++`** operations are actually translated into 3 instructions in machine-code ( see the symbolic assembly decode )?

```
LD    R0, X             // LOAD into R0 the value of x
INCR  R0 (or DECR R0)   // { INCR | DECR }-increase/decrease the value of R0 by 1
STO   R0, X             // STORE the new value back to x
```

If yes,
then what is the order of the instructions, so that the output **`"x=8"`** was generated?

If not,
then why does it occasionally print **`x=8`**?

Comment: What language is this? What processor? Can you show the actual assembly that is generated?

Comment: Note that in C your code has data-race undefined behaviour because `int x` isn't `_Atomic`.  Your asm is what you'd expect for compiling without optimization, but *with* optimization could optimize away the x-- and x++ that cancel each other, and hoist the load of `x` out of the loop, basically doing an infinite loop that's either empty or runs printf.  (This isn't an answer because it's not a C question, but instead an asm question assuming that it does compile naively to the instructions shown)  See also [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](//stackoverflow.com/q/39393850)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is entirely possible, and it is precisely due to the reason that you suspect, but not exactly in the order that you suspect.

The `x--` statement is not atomic, it consists of a load operation, a decrement operation, and a store operation.  So, if the `x--` gets pre-empted by the other thread, the result can be as if the `x--` statement did not execute at all.  But that would not yield an `8`, it would actually cause `x` to not reach a value as low as `8`.

However, the same holds true for the `x++` statement: pre-emption may cause an `x++` to never happen, so the result in that case would be that `x` would fail to exceed `9`, so it would then take only one successful `x--` to bring it down to `8`.

So, if more `x++`s are cancelled than `x--`s, then it is entirely possible that `x` would become 8.  Actually, in your code sample it is entirely possible that `x` could receive any value you can think of.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's because `x++` and `x--` are not atomic operations. If one of these operations is preempted, another thread might have changed the value of `x`, so the thread doing the increment or decrement operation stores a result that's computed from a stale value of `x`.

Here's a possible interleaving that leads to printing `x=9`, `x=8`, `x=9`. In this particular interleaving, the increment operations in P1 and P2 start from the same value of `x`, and therefore they both write the same result, so that `x` is effectively only incremented once.

```
P1          P2          x
                        10
LD R0, x                10
DECR R0                 10
ST R0, x                10→9
            LD R0, x    9
            DECR R0     9
            ST R0, x    9→8
            LD R0, x    8
LD R0, x                8
INCR R0                 8
ST R0, x                8→9
            INCR R0     9
            ST R0, x    9→9
            print       9
            GOTO loop   9
            LD R0, x    9
            DECR R0     9
            ST R0, x    8
print                   8
GOTO loop
            LD R0, x    8
            INCR R0     8
            ST R0, x    8→9
            print       9
            GOTO loop   9
```

Note that in this interleaving, the loop body is executed three times (once in P1 and once in P2), and the final value of `x` is not 10. A similar sequence could repeat and the value of `x` could end up being arbitrarily low. Symmetrically, it could end up being arbitrarily high.

Here's another interleaving where 8 is reached with a single iteration in each thread. In this one, the decrement operation in P2 effectively cancels the increment in P2. With this interleaving, the very first output is `x=8`, followed by `x=9`.

```
P1          P2          x
                        10
LD R0, x                10
DECR R0                 10
ST R0, x                10→9
            LD R0, x    9
            DECR R0     9
LD R0, x                9
INCR R0                 9
ST R0, x                9→10
            ST R0, x    10→8
            LD R0, x    8
print                   8
GOTO loop
            INCR R0     8
            ST R0, x    8→9
            print       9
            GOTO loop   9
```

Here's yet another interleaving where the output starts with `x=8`, `x=7`, `x=6`. Here the increment operations all happen to be effectively cancelled by a concurrent decrement. This could go on forever.

```
P1          P2          x
                        10
LD R0, x                10
DECR R0                 10
ST R0, x                10→9
            LD R0, x    9
            DECR R0     9
LD R0, x                9
INCR R0                 9
ST R0, x                9→10
            ST R0, x    10→8
            LD R0, x    8
print                   8
GOTO loop               8
LD R0, x                8
DECR R0                 8
            INCR R0     8
            ST R0, x    8→9
ST R0, x                9→7
LD R0, x                7
            print       7
            GOTO loop   7
            LD R0, x    7
INCR R0                 7
ST R0, x                8
            DECR R0     8
            ST R0, x    8→6
print                   6
GOTO loop               6
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *" ... **why** does it occasionally print `x=8`? "*

Because this is a very example of the by-product of executing un-coordinated concurrent operations in a *CRCW*-PRAM-abstract computing machine, as was explained in elementary theory of concurrent-processing :

```
parbegin P1(); P2();
parend;
```

as defined above does nothing else but unrestricted and principally colliding CRCW-operations on ***shared*** **`x`** ( i.e. **principally** - so independently from what kind of a compiler was thought to be used, what compilation tricks were thought to have been put in-place, and what target silicon was deemed to be used for loading & running such a code-execution product ( Be it RISC/CISC? Be it superscalar or not? Be it pipelined? Be it in-order/out-of-order executing? etc.) -- the problem starts from how the imperatively postulated code was designed (as it was), not by how the code-representation & transformation thereof did evolve or how the target silicon-device actually operates at bottom-most level at the end.

The responsibility for collision-avoidance is & always was on the author's side, wasn't it?

The code, designed as-is, above ***"shares"*** access to `x`, both on Read and Write, **constrained by *nothing*** - thus principally ***free***-to-collide whenever externally influenced "**order**-of-steps" gets skewed ( not meeting an expected sequence of steps `[do +1 <_almost_right_after_> -1 was done]`, deemed to maintain `x=10` invariant ( which it is not capable of, even in abstract, perfectly synchronous, ideal CRCW-PRAM machine )

[image]

As has been explained ages ago, in **Bernstein’s conditions** (*see [Theory](https://www.scribd.com/doc/53645670/Parallelism-in-Algorithms-Bernstein-s-Conditions) and [examples](https://people.engr.ncsu.edu/efg/501/f98/lectures/notes/lec4.html)* ), all *just*-`[CONCURRENT]` ( the more the True-`[PARALLEL]` ) code-execution units ***must* strictly control order** in which **shared variables** ( the **`x`**, in the mock-up code above) are read and updated.